# SQL Server : creating derived column

Tags: sql-server, derived

The following is the sample data for the table that I'm working. I looking to create a new column `RenIndicator` that is having 3 distinct values and this should be populated based on `NextPolicy` column and then `Expiry date` column.

Any thoughts will be good. Included the sample data and my expects results below.

New column `RenIndicator` and it has one of three possible values: `Yes`, `No`, `N/a yet`.

**Yes** - When the `NextPolicy` has a policynumber & `Expiry date` is the before the current date

**No** - When the `NextPolicy` column does not have any value & the `Expiry date` is less than the current date

**N/A yet** - When the `NextPolicy` column does not have any value & the `Expiry date` is greater than the current date

I'm looking query more like this

```
                select a.*, 
                        case when a.NextPolicy <> NULL and NewRenewal = 'New' then 'Renewal' ELSE
                         when a.NextPolicy = NULL and ExpiryDate > GETDATE() then 'Not Availble Yet' ELSE
                        when a.NextPolicy = NULL and ExpiryDate < GETDATE() then 'Not Availble Yet' 
                        end as 'Renewal Indicator'  
                        from final a
```

Sample data:

```
--===== If the test table already exists, drop it
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#mytable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #mytable

--===== Create the test table with 
CREATE TABLE #mytable 
(
    Region nvarchar(300), 
    NextPolicy nvarchar(300),
    CurrentPolicyNumber nvarchar(300),
    PolicyNumber nvarchar(100), 
    NewRenewal nvarchar(100), 
    EffectiveDate Date, 
    ExpiryDate Date, 
    Coverage nvarchar(100), 
    InsuredName nvarchar(300)
)

SET DATEFORMAT DMY

--===== Insert the test data into the test table
INSERT INTO #mytable (Region, NextPolicy, CurrentPolicyNumber, PolicyNumber, NewRenewal, EffectiveDate, ExpiryDate, Coverage, InsuredName)
    SELECT 'Asia', '47-ACA-000001-02', '47-ACA-000001-01', '000001', 'New', '2016-12-25', '2017-12-25', '', 'CPC Corporation, Taiwan (CPC)' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Asia', '', '47-ACA-000001-02', '000001', 'Renewal', '2017-12-25', '2018-12-25', '', 'CPC Corporation, Taiwan (CPC)' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'North America', '42-XPR-000001-02', '42-PRP-000001-01', '000001', 'New', '2013-05-15', '2014-05-15', 'PRP', 'AvalonBay Communities,Inc.' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'North America', '42-XPR-000001-03', '42-XPR-000001-02', '000001', 'Renewal', '2014-05-15', '2015-05-15', 'XPR', 'AvalonBay Communities, Inc.' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'North America', '42-XPR-000001-04', '42-XPR-000001-03', '000001', 'Renewal', '2015-05-15', '2016-05-15', 'XPR', 'AvalonBay Communities, Inc.' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'North America', '', '42-XPR-000001-04', '000001', 'Renewal', '2016-05-15', '2017-05-15', 'XPR', 'AvalonBay Communities, Inc.' 
    UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'Asia',         '47-ABA-000001-02','47-ABA-000001-01','000001','New',       '2015-11-25',   '2016-11-25','','Taiwan' UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'Asia',         '','47-ABA-000001-02','000001','Renewal','2016-11-25','2017-11-25','','Taiwan'
```

Comment: Which bucket do values go where ExpiryDate is  = to today's date?

Comment: That bucket is not needed for my analysis..

Comment: Ok just FYI those records will show up as `NULL` in the answer I provided since they are not handled in the CASE.

Comment: Also thanks for including all of the table structures and insert scripts it makes it a lot easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a case statement:

```
SELECT *
     , CASE WHEN NextPolicy <> '' AND ExpiryDate < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN NextPolicy = '' AND ExpiryDate < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN 'No'
            WHEN NextPolicy = '' AND ExpiryDate >  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN 'N/a yet'
       END AS RenIndicator
FROM #mytable
```

I've used the empty string `''` for the "does not have any value" requirement, but if you have NULLS in those fields you will need to do something like `ISNULL(NextPolicy, '')` in the CASE to account for them.

We are assuming that any value is a valid policy number as well. Additional data validation could be included as needed.

Also upcoming edit pending more information on what happens when the ExpiryDate is today's date.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly...

```
ALTER TABLE #mytable ADD RenIndicator AS CASE WHEN NULLIF(NextPolicy,'') IS NOT NULL AND ExpiryDate < GETDATE() THEN 'Yes'
                                              WHEN NULLIF(NextPolicy,'') IS NULL AND ExpiryDate < GETDATE() THEN 'No'
                                              WHEN NULLIF(NextPolicy,'') IS NULL THEN 'N/A yet'
                                         END;
```

This will, however, return *`NULL`* if `NextPolicy` does have a value and the renewal date is in the future.

I noticed your sample data had `''` in it, rather than *`NULL`* to show an absence of data, thus I've used `NULLIF`, just in case, however, you may be able to simply change this to `= ''` and `<> ''` or remove the `NULLIF`.

I've also assumed by your statement "I looking to create a new column `RenIndicator`" you do actually mean create a new column (alter to table's DDL).